# import excel file error python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, spyder

I have trouble loading excel files into a dataframe using ExcelFile(). I have imported pandas,xlrd and openpyxl. I am using spyder for interactive data analysis. 
I'm new to pandas and python, so I would appriciate an answer that is understandable for a beginner. Could someone help me?

```
>>> import xlrd
>>> import openpyxl
>>> from pandas import *
>>> xls = ExcelFile('C:\RWFC\test.xls')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1294, in __init__
self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(path_or_buf)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 400, in open_workbook
f = open(filename, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'C:\\RWFC\test.xls'
```

Comment: Try escaping your path using raw string: `xls = ExcelFile(r'C:\RWFC\test.xls')` or double backslashes: `xls = ExcelFile('C:\\RWFC\\test.xls')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
>>> xls = ExcelFile('C:\RWFC\test.xls')
```

The backward slash has a special meaning.  For example, the character "\t" in a normal string is the tab character:

```
>>> "\t"
'\t'
>>> len("\t")
1
```

That's why in your error message:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'C:\\RWFC\test.xls'
```

You see a double slash in front of the `R` -- `\R` doesn't have any special meaning, and so it knew you meant one "real" slash:

```
>>> s = "\\"
>>> s
'\\'
>>> print s
\
>>> len(s)
1
```

but `\t` does have a special meaning.  To solve this problem you can either use a "raw string", and add "r" before the string literal:

```
>>> "C:\RWFC\test.xls"
'C:\\RWFC\test.xls'
>>> r"C:\RWFC\test.xls"
'C:\\RWFC\\test.xls'
```

or, you can simply use forward slashes instead -- which Windows supports -- and avoid all the trouble:

```
>>> "C:/RWFC/test.xls"
'C:/RWFC/test.xls'
```

Either way should work.

Comment: Is really forward slash in path supported by Windows or is it more like support of Windows implementation of Python?

Comment: @Fenikso: the full story, as I understand it, is a little complicated-- see this thread [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2003-September/204269.html).  I think it basically boils down to this: "/" has pretty much always been accepted as a path delimiter since DOS days, but Windows command consoles typically reject it unquoted because they use it as an option flag, so people think that it's forbidden.  I'm only an occasional Windows user, though, so don't take my word on the history.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I solved it by adding an x to the path

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. I resolved the issue this way:

```
path = r"Drive:\path\to\your\file.extension"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(path) ##assuming you have imported xlrd already
```

Hope this helps. :)